# permissão de pasta php

Tags: php, apache

Tenho um sistema open source chamado NOVOSGA funcionando na minha máquina local, mas no servidor de hospedagem não funciona, quando eu tento rodar ele me dá um erro do próprio sistema:

```
Diretório temporário    /tmp    
Permissão requerida: Escrita    
Permissão atual: Somente leitura

Session Save Path   /var/lib/php/session/www.painel.sitepainel.com.br/
Permissão requerida: Escrita    
Permissão atual: Somente leitura
```

Entrei em contato com a hospedagem, e eles juram de pé junto que essas permissões já estão de escrita.

Eu vi no código que essas duas pastas podem ser acessadas com estes comandos no `php`: `sys_get_temp_dir()` e `session_save_path()`

É possível eu rodar algum comando em `php` que me diga a permissão atual destas pastas para eu enviar para o servidor de hospedagem?

Comment: É possível você acessar o servidor de hospedagem por SSH?

Comment: Você tem acesso ao `php.ini`? Se sim, pode tentar alterar o diretório da session para um temporário. `session.save_path = /tmp` onde /tmp é o que você saiba que tem permissão. Importante sempre fazer backup do arquivo `php.ini` antes de alterar.

Comment: não tenho acesso, é do servidor de hospedagem, só o que eles me dizem  é que já existem estas permissões, por isso queria algum comando que mostrasse na tela a permissão destas pastas

Comment: Você pode verificar se tem permissão de escrita usando a função is_writable(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

Comment: Voce tem algum tipo de acesso ssh ao seu servidor ?

Comment: Basta da uma permissão na sua pasta raiz 775 e se for preciso de tbm na pasta de cache.